# Bootstrap grid layout - what's the point of xs-columns?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Since the default behavior of columns on extra small screens is as follows (quote from the Bootstrap site):

> Horizontal at all times

I'm wondering what the point of `col-xs-*` is? On an xs device, the columns are gonna be stacked vertically anyway, so why bother using this kind of code?
Btw, I know that for instance `col-md-6` scales upwards. But what about downscaling, so in that example, if there's nothing declared for a small screen? Is there a default as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is so that you can stack items horizontally on screen sizes lower then `768px` without them stacking vertically. The column's will re-size as the viewport gets smaller without breaking to the next line. If there is anything in your page that you do not want to break at a given width then it is a good time to use `SX`.